# Calculating acceleration via differentiation of velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I am just starting with calculus and kinematics. I saw this particular question:

> The velocity of a particle at a distance $x$ is given by $v^2 = 4\cdot (x \sin (x) + \cos (x))$. Find the acceleration.

Now I know that $a$ = $\frac{dv}{dt}$. But here there is no t variable so shoud I differentiate it with respect to x? I don't think it will be possible as $x$ is the distance.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Related:  [What is the difference between implicit and explicit time dependence e.g. ∂ρ∂t and dρdt?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9122/9887)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get distance when acceleration is not constant?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15587/how-to-get-distance-when-acceleration-is-not-constant)

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61293/nonuniform-acceleration-due-to-rubber-rope

Comment: I was asking for the variable to differentiate, NOT THE SOLUTION to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that by chain rule, we have that $$a=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\cdot v=v\frac{dv}{dx}$$

Comment: Actually, I don't think there was need of any downvote as it just provided a hint to OP's HW query.

Answer (score 0):

I think what confused here is the difference between [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) and [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative). 
For example, 
$$\frac{d f(x)}{d t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d t}$$
But, 
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial t} = 0$$
So, in your question, you just do derivative on both side and notice that $\frac{d x}{d t} = v_x$ and $\frac{d v_x}{d t} = a$. Then, you could obtain $a$ by solve the equation.